# My code is username validation, user must be enter the word capital

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<cctype>

using namespace std;
string::size_type len;

class login{
private:
    char  name[10];
    string password;

public:
    login()
    {
        strcpy(name,"0");
        password="0";
    }
    void user()
    {
        cout<<"enter the user name::";
        cin>>name;
    }

    char user_varification()
    {
        user();                    
        for(int i=1;i<=name.length();i++){                      
            if(isupper(name[i]))
                cout<<name[i];
        }
    }                                               
};

int main()
{
    //cout<<"user name should be is capitallater"<<endl<<"length must be minimum 6 characher and user name "<<endl;//
    login s;
    s.user_varification();
    system ("pause");
}
```

Error message

```
29  C:\Users\Adeel Haider\Desktop\hellow.cpp
[Error] request for member 'length' in '((login*)this)->login::name', which is of non-class type 'char [10]'
```

Comment: The title should reflect the problem you are having, not what overall goal of the program is.

Comment: only check the capitalization word user enter the word and check the word the word is capital or not using the isupper function

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty self explanatory.  `name` is of the type `char[]` and has no member function called `length()`.  Change `name` to be of type `std::string` like password is.

Comment: @GhulamHaider What's actually unclear about the explanation?? _"Change `name` to be of type `std::string` like `password` is."_